# Can vmlinux be used instead of uImage?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, u-boot

I want to use an uncompressed kernel image and boot the BeagleBoard. Generally I use uImage to boot the kernel which is in compressed format. How do I use an uncompressed kernel image?

Comment: You are using U-Boot as the bootloader, right?

Comment: yes! Is it possible using uboot?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, U-Boot cannot directly boot a “raw” ELF image (`vmlinux`). You need to turn it into the `uImage` format, which contains the compressed `vmlinux` plus a few extra bytes of metadata that describe the kernel load address. [U-Boot FAQ 2.19](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/HowCanICreateAnUImageFromAELFFile) explains how to generate `uImage`; it's fairly straightforward, using the `mkimage` utility in the U-Boot source tree:

```
 mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C gzip … -d vmlinux uImage
```

(You may need extra parameters indicating the load address.)

Comment: Uncompressing the uImage while booting takes some time. I need to minimize that. So i thought why dont i try with the uncompressed raw file vmlinux.

Comment: The effect you want to achieve might be opposite to intended. Decompression time is usually smaller than time of copying data from flash.

Comment: If you are using ubifs for the root image, it is already compressed somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

```
 mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C gzip … -d vmlinux uImage
```

Change *gzip* in the above example to *none*, and you'll create a u-Boot compatible uncompressed image.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Buildroot, select a `uImage` kernel output file (`BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_UIMAGE=y`).  Compile normally and Buildroot will also create a `vmlinux` file in an intermediate step.  While the `vmlinux` file is not copied to the `/output/images` directory it can be found in `./output/build/linux-custom/`(or by running `find . -name "vmlinux"`).