# can I use vmlinux instead of vmlinuz with GRUB2 (Fedora)?

Tags: fedora, grub2, boot-loader

Can I use `vmlinux` instead of `vmlinuz` with `GRUB2` (`Fedora`)?

I've seen this:

[Can vmlinux be used instead of uImage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30990/can-vmlinux-be-used-instead-of-uimage)

but it speaks of `U-Boot`, not `GRUB2`.